# Context on Adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to send the context from my java class to my adapter of a `RecyclerView`, so I can click on the elements and be redirected to an intent. Apparently, the context isn't right. I've commented its line and the app works, but as soon as i try to prove it, it starts crashing again.
I assume its a context thing, but it would be pretty helpful if there's another way to set a click method to my elements.

The exception it throw its a null pointer exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference

Here is the adapter code:

```
public class SubsidioAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubsidioAdapter.SubsidioViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Producto> productoList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SubsidioAdapter(Context context, List<Producto> productoList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productoList = productoList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public SubsidioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_item, null);
        return new SubsidioViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SubsidioViewHolder subsidioViewHolder, int position) {
        subsidioViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(this.productoList.get(position).getFoto());
        subsidioViewHolder.textView1.setText(this.productoList.get(position).getNombre());
        subsidioViewHolder.textView2.setText(this.productoList.get(position).getDescripcion());
        subsidioViewHolder.textView3.setText(this.productoList.get(position).getPrecio());
        subsidioViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                context.startActivity(new
                        Intent(context, ModificarProductoActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.productoList.size();
    }

    public class SubsidioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        TextView textView3;

        public SubsidioViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotoSub);
            this.textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descSub);
            this.textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreSub);
            this.textView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioSub);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its a null pointer exception:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proingsoftware/proingsoftware.activities.funcionario.ModificarProductoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: its not a button, its an element from my recycler view, on any element clicked it should intent

Comment: Your exception says ```Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference``` which means you are setting a listener on a null ```Button```

Comment: but theres no button declared and i dont use none on that activity :(

Comment: When does the crash happen? What do you do to get a crash? Tap on an item of the RV?

Comment: yes, the idea is to tap on a rv and be redirected to another activity, instead; it crashes

Comment: If that's the case then your crash log is not correct.Provide the correct log. Also, did you try the answer provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set an id to root element of adapter item layout, then find that view by id and use it instead of `itemView` ,
instead of :

```
subsidioViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
          ...
        }
    });
```

use:

```
subsidioViewHolder.rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
              ...
            }
        });
```

. and remember you can get context in recyclerView adapter inside onCreateViewHolder() without using constructor like this:

```
@Override
public SubsidioViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    context=viewGroup.getContext();
    View view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_item, null);
    return new SubsidioViewHolder(view);
}
```

although it seems like that your problem is with